# Query for intersection data C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, data-mining, depth-first-search

I have 9 sample transactions with 5 items:

```
[Table 1]
itemset | TID_set
--------+---------------------------------------
a       | 100, 400, 500, 700, 800, 900
b       | 100, 200, 300, 400, 600, 800, 900
c       | 300, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900
d       | 200, 400
e       | 100, 800

[Table 2]
itemset | TID_set
--------+----------------------
a, b    | 100, 400, 800, 900
a, c    | 500, 700, 800, 900
a, d    | 400
a, e    | 100, 800
b, c    | 300, 600, 800, 900
b, d    | 200, 400
b, e    | 100, 800
c, e    | 800

[Table 3]
itemset | TID_set
--------+-----------
a, b, c | 800, 900
a, b, e | 100, 800
```

I want to display the data as in `Table 3` using depth-first search algorithm, but the results are not the same as the `table 3`. This is my source code :

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table" + (k) + " SELECT DISTINCT ";

        for (int i = 1; i <= k - 1; i++)
        {
            query = query + "P.itemset" + i + ", ";
        }
        query = query + "Q.itemset" + (k - 1) + ",(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table1.TID_set) FROM table1 WHERE table1.TID_set = ANY(SELECT table1.TID_set FROM table1 WHERE table1.itemset IN( ";


        for (int i = 1; i <= k - 1; i++)
        {
            query = query + "P.itemset" + i + ",";
        }

        query = query + "Q.itemset" + (k - 1) + ") GROUP BY table1.TID_set HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table1.itemset)>=" + k + "))";
        query = query + "FROM table" + (k - 1) + " P , table" + (k - 1) + " Q WHERE Q.itemset" + (k - 1) + " > P.itemset" + (k - 1) + " ";

        for (int i = 2; i < k - 1; i++)
        {
            query = query + "AND P.itemset" + i + " > P.itemset" + (i - 1) + " ";
        }

        query = query + "ORDER BY ";

        for (int i = 1; i <= k - 1; i++)
        {
            query = query + "P.itemset" + i + ",";
        }

        query = query + "Q.itemset" + (k - 1) + "";
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store data as comma separated items in a column. It will cause lots of problems when writing queries. Normally you store one value per row.

Comment: it's just an example, actually data store does not use a comma to separate each transaction id, but I store one value per row. it is only for representation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why the famous **APRIORI** algorithm does not query the database once for each item set combination, but only *scans* it once per itemset length: this is already expensive enough.

It doesn't help if you try to cram everything into one big SQL query.

Your approach will not scale to any meaningful data set because of size.

It will be much easier if you treat the database simply as a data store, read transactions from it, and do the actual algorithm in your C# program instead of abusing SQL for something that it was not designed for...